# hard-to-understand error in an augmented assignment statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, assignment-operator

This is a contrived example for the sake of my understanding Kotlin language.
The class `Box<T>` below models a box that contains boxes of the same type T.

The question is why `arr += x` causes compile error while `arr.add(x)` does not.
The error message is:

> Type mismatch. Required: kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Box>
>
> Found: List<Box>

the property `arr` is immutable and points to a mutable list. So I believe there is no ambiguity whether `arr += x` should mean `arr = arr + x` or `arr.add(x)`. It should mean `arr.add(x)`

I also noticed that the issue is gone if generic type `Box` implements `Iterable<T>` instead of `Iterable<Box<T>>`

So, what is the reason of the error?

```
class Box<T>(private val arr: ArrayList<Box<T>> = ArrayList()) : Iterable<Box<T>> {
    private val id: Int = seq++

    override operator fun iterator(): Iterator<Box<T>> {
        return object : Iterator<Box<T>> { 
            private var i = 0;
            override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
                return i < arr.size
            }

            override fun next(): Box<T> {
                return arr[i++]
            }
        }
    }

    fun add(x: Box<T>) {
        // arr.add(x) // OK 
        arr += x // Error: Type mismatch.
    }

    companion object {
        var seq: Int = 0
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Box[$id]"
    }
}

fun main() {
    val box = Box<Int>(arrayListOf(Box(), Box()))
    for (x in box) {
        println(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr += x` is neither `arr = arr + x` (though it could be in other cases) nor `arr.add(x)` (not *directly*, at least). It is just a call to the [`plusAssign`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html) operator function.

There are many overloads of `plusAssign`. The relevant ones to this question are:

```
operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(
    element: T)

operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(
    elements: Iterable<T>)
```

The first overload would call `arr.add(x)`, and the second would call `arr.addAll(x)`.

The problem is, *both of these* are applicable in your case, but there is no "most specifc" overload among them.

The first overload is trivially applicable, and the second overload is applicable because `x` is also a `Iterable<Box<T>>` because of the interface implementation.

None of these are more specific because none of them can "forward" the call to the other. An overload is the most specific if it is the single overload that can "forward" to all the other applicable overloads. In this case:

```
fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.plusAssign1(x: T) {
    this.plusAssign2(x) // does not compile
}
fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.plusAssign2(x: Iterable<T>) {
    this.plusAssign1(x) // also does not compile
}
```

See also the [Kotlin Language Specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#choosing-the-most-specific-candidate-from-the-overload-candidate-set).

I would just call `add` manually to fix the error, instead of using operators.